# IntelliTrace not logging

Tags: wpf, intellitrace

I have been using IntelliTrace.exe for wpf application to collect the iTrace log. IntelliTrace.exe resides in the below system path 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools"

When I use IntelliTrace with launch switch its working fine.

IntelliTrace.exe launch /cp:"mycollectionplan.xml" /f:"iTraceFilewithFullpath" "ApplicationwithFullpath" - LAUNCH CMD

But when I use IntelliTrace with start or run,iTrace file of size around 160,000 KB has been created and when I stop it it turns back to 576 KB

IntelliTrace.exe start /cp:"mycollectionplan.xml" /f:"iTraceFilewithFullpath" "ApplicationwithFullpath" - START CMD

IntelliTrace.exe run /cp:"mycollectionplan.xml" /f:"iTraceFilewithFullpath" "ApplicationwithFullpath" - RUN CMD

IntelliTrace.exe stop /cp:"mycollectionplan.xml" /f:"iTraceFilewithFullpath" "ApplicationwithFullpath" - STOP CMD

Please advise on this issue

Let me know do we have any way to start and stop logger whenever needed

Answer (score 1):

I have a few comments.

1. *launch* switch works because it starts an application and IntelliTrace logger and attaches IntelliTrace to this application.
2. *run* / *start* switches do something different. They only start IntelliTrace logger. The application should be started later manually. However, it should be started in the proper way (I'll desribe it later).
3. If you run either *IntelliTrace help run* comamnd or *IntelliTrace help switch* command in the command line, you will see that these switches do not expect a path to your application.
4. The only difference between *run* and *start* switches is that *start* switch starts IntelliTrace logger in the background.
5. You shouldn't start (as in your example) two IntelliTrace loggers that will use the same log.

**Here is an example showing how to use *start* switch**

In the command line do the following steps. Firstly let's start IntelliTrace logger called **test**:

*IntelliTrace.exe start /n:test /f:iTraceFilewithFullpath /cp:mycollectionplan.xml*

Now we need to enable profiling:

*set COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1*

Now we should say which profiler we want to use. It is important to use a proper identifier/GUID here. I'll explain how to find it later.

*set COR_PROFILER={b19f184a-cc62-4137-9a6f-af0f91730165}*

The next step is to say which IntelliTrace logger we want to use to monitor our application. In our case it's called **test**:

*set VSLOGGERNAME=test*

Now we are ready to start our program:

*ApplicationwithFullpath*

At the end we should stop IntelliTrace logger:

*IntelliTrace.exe stop /n:test /cp:mycollectionplan.xml*

**How to find GUID of Intellitrace?**

1. Start IntelliTrace using *launch* switch.
2. Start [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/processexplorer).
3. Find your application in the tree of all processes.
4. Right click it and select *Properties...*
5. Go to *Environment* tab.
6. Find *COR_PROFILER* variable.
7. Copy it's value. It's our GUID.

As you can see it is much more easier to use *launch* switch.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But still i'm experiencing same problem.
"I use IntelliTrace with start or run,iTrace file of size around 160,000 KB has been created and when I stop it it turns back to 576 KB"

Comment: I'm sure that the approach described by me works in practise because I use it. It means that you must do something in a different way. My guess is that your collection plan is wrong. 
Did you try to use a default collection plan, for example the one that is distributed with the standalone collector?
Can you publish somewhere your collection plan?

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you don't cap the log file size in your collection plan? The maximum log file can be set with .