# Issue with the iTrace log file, truncated to 640KB

Tags: c#, production-environment, intellitrace

We are trying to get Itrace file from production domain.

Steps followed to get sample iTrace file.
1.  After download and expand cab file the IntelliTraceSC.exe resides in C:\IntelliTraceCollector

2. If the iTrace log file is collected from launch command , file is in proper size  and able to investigate in VS Enterprise 2017.
   C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe launch /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.Trace.xml" /f:"C:\DumpFile\testlog.itrace" "CApplicationFullPath"
3. But the scenario expected is to get the iTrace log in the background. i.e user will launch the application is installed folder and Itrace should be logged in case of exception.

Tried with start command.
C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe start /name:logger /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.Trace.xml" /f:"C:\DumpFile\itracefile.itrace"

set VSLOGGERNAME=logger

and  COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1  COR_PROFILER={aaaaaa70-dfed-4cb4-a1d6-920f51e9674a} is set in System Environment variable.

After executing the START command  this size of itracefile is 16432KB .
Process is started from installed application path eg C:\Program Files\ApplicationFolder\test.exe

After the application is exit , IntelliTraceSC is not releasing the iTrace log file and its not stopping the Log.
So stopped logger using STOP command.

C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe stop /name:logger /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.Trace.xml"

After STOP Command logging file size is 640kb. 
We tried changing MaximumFileSizes in Collection_Plan  but still we could not get ITrace log file.

Referred Link : [IntelliTrace not logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912563/intellitrace-not-logging)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65464517-8ec5-4a5a-a36d-89812b659114/intellitrace-not-logging?forum=vsdebug
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msaffer/2010/12/07/using-intellitrace-outside-the-ide-64-bit-applications/

How to get the itrace log file after the application is exited?

Comment: Do you try to use IntelliTraceSC.exe to collect the iTrace file of a running application? I'm afraid that's not supported. The application should be launched by IntelliTraceSC.exe.